# Configurable Joint: yDrive mode - brackeys multiplayer fps

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As you may know, the mode for the configurable spring has been removed, and I've discovered this following a Brackeys tutorial on multiplayer fps (part 5). There was a comment under the video saying that you should ignore this as Brackeys sets it manually in the code later. However, when I did this, there was no errors, but the jump button did nothing (yes I checked the inputs)

My code is below:

```
using UnityEngine;
[RequireComponent(typeof(PlayerMotor))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(ConfigurableJoint))]

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Vector3 _movHorizontal;
    private Vector3 _movVertical;
    private Vector3 _velocity;
    
    [SerializeField]
    private float speed = 5f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float lookSensitivity = 5f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float thrusterForce = 1000f;

    [Header("Spring Settings:")]
    [SerializeField]
    private JointDriveMode jointMode = JointDriveMode.Position;
    [SerializeField]
    private float jointSpring = 20f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float joinMaxForce = 40f;


    private PlayerMotor motor;
    private ConfigurableJoint joint;

    void Start ()
    {
        motor = GetComponent<PlayerMotor>();
        joint = GetComponent<ConfigurableJoint>();

        SetJointSettings(jointSpring);
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        //Calc movement velocity as Vector 3D
        float _xMov = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float _zMov = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        _movHorizontal = transform.right * _xMov;
        _movVertical = transform.forward * _zMov;

        //Final movement vector
        _velocity = (_movHorizontal + _movVertical).normalized * speed;

        //Apply movement
        motor.Move(_velocity); 

        //Calculate rotation as a 3d vector (turning around)
        float _yrot = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X");
        
        Vector3 _rotation = new Vector3 (0f, _yrot, 0f) * lookSensitivity;

        //Apply rotation
        motor.Rotate(_rotation);

        //Calculate rotation as a 3d vector (turning around)
        float _xrot = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y");
        
        Vector3 _cameraRotation = new Vector3 (_xrot, 0f, 0f) * lookSensitivity;

        //Apply rotation
        motor.RotateCamera(_cameraRotation);

        //Calculate thruster force based on player input
        Vector3 _thrusterForce = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
        if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
        {
            _thrusterForce = Vector3.up * thrusterForce;
            SetJointSettings(0f);
        } else 
        {
            SetJointSettings(jointSpring);
        }

        //Apply thruster force
        motor.ApplyThruster(_thrusterForce);

    }

    private void SetJointSettings(float _jointSpring)
    {
            
        joint.yDrive = new JointDrive
        {
            mode = jointMode,
            positionSpring = _jointSpring, 
            maximumForce = joinMaxForce 
        };


    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: is the reason the jump script isnt working the fact that the mode was removed, or is there  a way to use the mode in the new version. If not, is there a replacement?